# Log-transformations and concave functions

Tags: linear-model, logarithm

Consider a linear equation $O = SW$ with $O \in \mathbb{R}^{g \times n}, S \in \mathbb{R}^{g \times k}, W \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$, with $g \gg n, g \gg k, k < n$. $W$ is a frequency matrix and each of its columns must add up to 1. I am reading a scientific paper that makes the following claim:

> Since $W$ is a frequency matrix and its column values sum to 1, the
>   following is true by the properties of concave functions: $\log(SW) >
>  \log(S)W$.

I do not know how to interpret this statement. Both $\log(SW)$ and $\log(S)W$ are matrices, so what does it mean for one matrix to be larger than another? Or is this statement meant to be entry-wise? Furthermore, if it is entrywise, I cannot prove the statement to be true with a simple simulation:

```
tablelist <- list()
for(i in 1:10){
  set.seed(i)
  S <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 5, data = rnorm(50, mean = 50, sd = 3))
  W <- matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 100, data = rnorm(500, mean = 1, sd = 0.5))
  W <- apply(W, 2, function(x) x/sum(x))

  tablelist[[i]] <- table((log(S %*% W)) > (log(S) %*% W))
}
```

This results in:

```
do.call(rbind, tablelist)

     FALSE TRUE
 [1,]     8  992
 [2,]     3  997
 [3,]     1  999
 [4,]     1  999
 [5,]    13  987
 [6,]     9  991
 [7,]     8  992
 [8,]     9  991
 [9,]     7  993
[10,]     6  994
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is a typo and it should be '$\geq$' instead of just '$>$'. Then it holds component wise by [Jensens inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality):

The entries of SW look like

$$(SW)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n S_{ik} W_{kj}$$
and now $\sum W_{kj} = 1$ hence,
  $$\log\left((SW)_{ij}\right) \geq \sum_{k=1}^n \log(S_{ik}) W_{kj} = \left(\log(S)W\right)_{ij}$$